# Does using centralized services defeat the benefits of a distributed blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

I'm reading about the blockchain concepts and there is one big thing i don't get: why in fact you need blockchain services such as https://www.ibm.com/blockchain/ or https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/blockchain/?v=17.23h

The entire concept of blockchain is that it is decentralized, doesn't going to a blockchain service break that idea entirely?

Why would someone need blockchain as a service?

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strip/1995-11-17

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to this but learning as fast as I can. Here's my understanding.

> Why would someone need blockchain as a service?

There are [many applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain#Applications) for a decentralized database. Crypto currencies are one notable use, and (I believe) where the concept started. Blockchains could also be useful for transaction processing, identity management, logistics, medical records, etc.

> The entire concept of blockchain that it is decentralized, isn't going to a blockchain service breaks the it entirly?

It depends on the purpose of your blockchain. In the case of Bitcoin, decentralization is a core concept which the entire project depends upon. If a small business wants to use this as a way to store transactional data then a couple of servers in the US may be all they need. Hence these service offerings.

Answer (score -1):

> Why would someone need blockchain as a service?

Because a lot of people think that they will be able to make profit with it

Comment: I did not ask for conspiracy theories, the entire thing is based on proffits, im asking about business logic or a business case.